# GCJ on SnowLeopard

Tags: macos, gcj

I do not know if this is the right place to ask this question.. but...

do you know if there is some installer of gcj available (or some way to install it) for Mac OS X 10.6?

I tried to install the MacPorts one but it has compilation errors.